# $a \cot A + b \cot B + c \cot C = 2(R+ r)$

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

With usual notations, prove that in a triangle $ABC$:

$$a \cot A + b \cot B + c \cot C = 2(R+ r)$$

I know $R = (abc)/(4\Delta)$ and $r = \Delta/s$.

I could not understand how to start it.

Comment: Please edit the question using http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
a \cot A + b \cot B + c \cot C &= 2R\Bigg[\sin A \frac{\cos A}{\sin A} + \sin B \frac{\cos B}{\sin B} + \sin C \frac{\cos C}{\sin C}\Bigg]\\
&= 2R\big[\cos A + \cos B +\cos C\big]\\
&= 2R\Bigg[2\cos \frac{A+B}{2}\cos \frac{A-B}{2} + 1-2\sin^2 \frac{C}{2}\Bigg]\\
&=2R\Bigg[1+ 2\sin \frac{A}{2}\sin \frac{B}{2} \sin \frac{C}{2}\Bigg]\\ &=2R\Big[1+\frac{r}{R}\Big] =2(R+r).
\end{align}
 Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, @juniven.

Comment: welcome and advance happy new year.--:D

Answer (score 1):

$\sum a\cot A = \sum \dfrac{a}{\sin A}\cos A = \sum 2R\cos A = 2R(1+\dfrac{r}{R}) = 2(r+R)$, where $\sum\cos A = 1+\dfrac{r}{R}$, is found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734395/how-to-prove-that-fracrr1-cos-a-cos-b-cos-c).