# Prove that sin A/2 * sin B/2 * sin C/2 = r/4R

Tags: trigonometry

The other day I came across an identity in the book "Problems from the Book" and it was presented as well known:

$$\sin \frac{A}{2} \cdot \sin \frac{B}{2} \cdot \sin \frac{C}{2} = \frac{r}{4R}$$

However I wasn't familiar with thee identity so I tried proving it.

Here is part of my attempt in solving this problem:

I first rewrote $\sin \frac{A}{2} \cdot \sin \frac{B}{2} \cdot \sin \frac{C}{2}$ as $\frac{r^3}{AI\cdot BI \cdot CI}$ (where I is the incenter of $\bigtriangleup ABC$). Then I tried using the fact that [ABC] =abc/4R (where [ABC] represents the area of $\bigtriangleup ABC$)which allowed me to rewrite the equation as $\frac{r^2}{AI\cdot BI \cdot CI} = \frac{[ABC]}{abc}$. I tried various things at this point but none of my attempts were successful...

Does anyone have a proof of this identity?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [half-angle formulae in terms of $a,b,c,s$](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/Solving_triangles_by_half-angle_formulae)?

Comment: You need to add a definition for what $A, B, C, r$ and $R$ are. Otherwise this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: It is interesting to note that each of the inradius, and the exradii, $r,r_a,r_b,r_c$ all have similar formulae, with $r_a$ having two external angles bisected in $B,C$, so that we will have $$r_a = 4R\sin\left( \dfrac{A}2 \right)\sin\left( \dfrac{\pi - B}2 \right)\sin\left( \dfrac{\pi - C}2 \right) \\ = 4R\sin\left( \dfrac{A}2 \right)\cos\left( \dfrac{B}2 \right)\cos\left( \dfrac{C}2 \right)$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734395/how-to-prove-that-fracrr1-cos-a-cos-b-cos-c and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176892/prove-trigonometry-identity-for-cos-a-cos-b-cos-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$LHS = \sin \frac{A}{2} \cdot \sin \frac{B}{2} \cdot \sin \frac{C}{2} $$

$$= \sqrt{\frac{(s-b)(s-c)}{bc}} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{(s-c)(s-a)}{ca}}  \cdot \sqrt{\frac{(s-a)(s-b)}{ab}}$$

$$= \frac{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}{abc}$$

Note that $$r = \frac{\Delta}{s}$$
$$R = \frac{abc}{4 \Delta}$$
$$\Delta^2 = s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$$
Now $$ RHS = \frac{r}{4R} = \frac{\Delta}{s} \cdot \frac{\Delta}{abc} = \frac{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}{abc}$$

Hence LHS = RHS

Comment: How exactly is $\sin\frac A2=\sqrt\frac{(s-b)(s-c)}{bc}$? thanks!

Comment: Please see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/Solving_triangles_by_half-angle_formulae

Comment: thanks you very much for the resource! .